# Can't access parameters from model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to validate few things using before_create and after save in my rails application model but I can not access parameters from model. When I use it I get error, params not found. How can I access the params from model?

Comment: Models, in general, should not be aware of anything coming directly from the web layer. Why do you need to access params directly?

Comment: can you paste the code where you are getting problem

Comment: @NitinJ The part where the model accesses `params`.

Comment: I need this for validation purpose. If I can not access it directly then how can I access it. I can not send those variables from controller since before_create and after_save methods are called automatically.

Comment: @user1478137 Use virtual attributes?

Comment: yes virtual attribute is the way you can do that , params can never be accessed in model

Answer (score 0):

Without the code it's hard to say. But you probably have to define the params in a private part of the model like so:

```
private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_sesh
    @sesh = Sesh.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def sesh_params
    params.require(:sesh).permit(:name, :ended_at)
  end
```

Comment: could you explain this line of code a little bit please? params.require(:sesh).permit(:name, :ended_at)

Comment: strong parameters is new in rails 4: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/3/21/strong-parameters/

Comment: So the strong params syntax is a little dumb. require(:model).permit(:attributes)

require doesn't make sense, I know its an issue on the strong parameters github.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this before  creating the record

```
m = Model.new(........

m.save_params(params)

if m.save
  ..........
  ..........
```

In model

```
def save_params(params)
  @params = params
end
```

Now you can use @params in before_create and after_save